# how can I dynamically change the image path in my POPOVER when I change my page in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to change this path `Images/mapCompany.jpg` dynamically when user click on every link in my page.

It just work on default page or home page.

**HTML code:**

```
<span id="mapshowing" class="label label-default" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" title="Test Title">TEST</span>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
function MapPOContent() {
    var mapCompany = "Images/mapCompany.jpg";
    var popOverContent = "<img class='center-block' src=" + mapCompany + " alt='logo' />";
    return popOverContent;
}

$('#mapshowing').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    content: function () {
        return MapPOContent();
    }
});
```

And if the user goes to this path, it doesn’t show any thing in popover “/Home/Contact”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a "/" in the url path. The leading slash means "from the root of the site", not "from my current folder".

```
var mapCompany = "/Images/mapCompany.jpg";
```